# I'm trying to make a loop

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class New {
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name... ");
        do{JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "YOUR NAME...");}
        while(name.equals(""));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello and welcome!, "+name);

        int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age... "));
        if(age>=60) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok Boomer!");
        System.exit(0);}
        else if(age>=18) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adult, Welcome!");
        }
        else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a kid!");
        System.exit(0);}

        String day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the day? ");

        if(day.equals("Monday")) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Java club!");
        }
        else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again later!");
        }
        
    }
}
```

**I want my loop to start when no name is entered and ends when there is a name, it keeps me in loop even when I enter a name (I'm a beginner)**

Comment: You don't update `name` inside your do-while loop.

Comment: The very first sentence of [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/JavaStyle.html) says "One goal of a programming course is for you to learn to write programs that are not only correct but also understandable." While I shouldn't advocate for any one style, I do believe your use of indentation makes the code less readable. My hope is that your code will be easier to understand after you change its style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the name variable in the do while loop.
Try this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class New {
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name... ");
        while(name.equals("")){
             name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "YOUR NAME...");
        }
        

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello and welcome!, "+name);

        int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age... "));
        if(age>=60) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok Boomer!");
        System.exit(0);}
        else if(age>=18) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adult, Welcome!");
        }
        else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are a kid!");
        System.exit(0);}

        String day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the day? ");

        if(day.equals("Monday")) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Java club!");
        }
        else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again later!");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It still shows "YOUR NAME..." even when I write a name in the first input dialog.
I want it to ignore the "YOUR NAME..." if I wrote a name, and show it if I didn't enter a name(all about the first input dialog, the second one works fine).

Comment: @O.M.A.R i modified my code, you don't need a do while loop, but just a simple while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update `name` in your loop.
Instead of:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name... ");
        do{JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "YOUR NAME...");}
        while(name.equals(""));
```

do:

```
String name;
        do{
              name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name... ");
        while(name.equals(""));
```